# Where's the most appropriate place to post a general graphics programming question?

Tags: discussion

A recent [question about raytracing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26773/11686) recieved a comment that it had nothing to do with game development. While that may be true, is there another place where the question would be more appropriate?

I feel that of all the disciplines covered by StackExchange, game development is the one most closely related to graphics programming, and that general graphics programming knowledge, whether real-time or not, is most useful to the game development community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow. There's no reason they can't answer graphics questions. Indeed, their OpenGL tag gets much more volume than ours.

> that general graphics programming knowledge, whether real-time or not, is most useful to the game development community.

If I want information about raytracing, I wouldn't go to a game developer. Yes, they *might* know, but there are a *lot* of graphics programmers who don't touch game development. And most game developers, even those who specialize in graphics, don't know much about raytracing beyond the basics.

Comment: Roger. A search did reveal many questions related to raytracing on StackOverflow already. I guess I don't know know too well what's the intended scope for StackOverflow, as I only tend to use it for general programming questions. So in that sense, I wouldn't normally go to StackOverflow for a graphics question, but that might have been my misconception.